# Raspberry Pi Pico charging MOSFET schematic

Tags: mosfet, p-channel, raspberry-pi-pico

As per the recommendation of Raspberry Pi Pico, using a P-channel enhancement type MOSFET (DMG2305UX) to switch the the power to VSYS pin isolating the battery when VBUS is available.

The schematic is as follows. I am not very familiar with MOSFETs and not sure if I need to add more protection components to the MOSFET circuit. Also the documentation refers the use of Schottky diode if required.

Please confirm if the given schematic is enough to power the Pico with a battery.

[image: MOSFET Schematic]

[Pico documentation](https://datasheets.raspberrypi.com/pico/pico-datasheet.pdf)

Comment: Numerically what are the voltages on all nodes in your circuit? What range can they have?

Comment: Maybe you want to add that you're referring to chapters 4.5 and 4.6 of the Pico datasheet.